# How can I configure proxy settings for applications that do not respect http_proxy and no_proxy env vars

Tags: linux, iptables, routing, proxy

I am running an application within a container, that does not work with the environment variables `http_proxy`, `http_proxy` and `no_proxy`. Since the Application doesn't respect the env vars, are there any options how to route traffic with linux system settings? Something like `iptables`, etc (would need some help here).

Details:
Every external domain should be routed through the proxy server (no authentication). And all internal traffic should not go through the proxy. Internal traffic is specified in the `no_proxy` var (something like: `*.cluster.local`, `*.myinternal.domain.com`).

Basically the same behavior like the env vars (`http_proxy`, `https_proxy`, `no_proxy`), but baked in without using them. 
Right now the docker image is based on centos but could be alpine soon.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like [tsocks](https://linux.die.net/man/8/tsocks) or [proxychains](https://github.com/rofl0r/proxychains-ng). Both of them use a configuration file, where you can set exceptions (I think).